# Leaflet ajax query to get lines from PostGIS problem when loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, leaflet, postgis

I have a strange issue with my Leaflet/Javascript code. I'm trying to refactor my application which was initially getting line data from PostGIS as a certain layer checkbox has been checked:

[image]

Then it bound some popups etc. It was working fine, but each time it was collecting all checked boxes values and sending it through ajax to PostGIS query and getting JSON response into `queryLayer`. So that each time some checkbox has been changed, the current `queryLayer` has been removed and loaded again with new data.

After my refactor I'm now able to:

1. Create a dedicated variable for layer as the checkbox is clicked using `window[checkboxValue]` (which allows me to create var names dynamically) and populate it with PostGIS geometry using ajax.
2. Once a particular checkbox is unchecked - then I'm removing this `window[uncheckedValue]` by `layer.id` var.

My problem is that after checking the second layer checkbox it is added into the map correctly and its popups/click events work fine, but **first** (previous) layer, although is visible as desired, popups/click events are not possible anymore for it.

NOTE: I've tried both:

- separate layers: `window[checkedTrasa]= L.geoJSON(JSON.parse(response), {...}`
- `L.featureGroup()` and adding/removing layers from group

```html
var myRenderer = L.canvas({ padding: 0.5, tolerance: 20 });
var trasyAll = L.featureGroup();
var R10
var WTR
$('input[name="trasy_checkbox"]').click(function() {
        var myRenderer = L.canvas({ padding: 0.5, tolerance: 20 });
        if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
          mymap.eachLayer(function (layer) {
            if (layer.id === removeTrasa )  {
                mymap.removeLayer(layer)
                var queryTrasy;
            }
        })};
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $.ajax({
            url:'script.php',
            type:'POST',
            data:{
                wybor_trasy: checkedTrasa
            },
            success: function(response){
                window[checkedTrasa]= L.geoJSON(JSON.parse(response), {
                    onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
                        var str = "blahblah";
                        layer.bindPopup(str, {
                            maxWidth: "auto"
                        });
                        layer.setStyle(StanOdcinkaStyle(layer));
                        layer.setStyle({renderer: myRenderer});
                        layer.bindTooltip('<img src="images/r10-13.png" height="20"/>');
                        layer.on('mouseover', function () {
                          this.setStyle({
                            opacity: 0.6,
                            weight: 6
                          });
                        });
                        layer.on('mouseout', function () {
                          this.setStyle(StanOdcinkaStyle(this));
                          this.setStyle({
                            opacity: 1,
                            weight: 4
                          });
                        });
                }})
                window[checkedTrasa].id = checkedTrasa;
                window[checkedTrasa].addTo(trasyAll);
            }
            });
       }
   }); 
  trasyAll.addTo(mymap);
```

Both layers are visible in Firefox debugger, but I don't know what should I look for exactly to see why only the last added layer is 'interactive', while the other one is not:
[in the red box you can see that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEodT.png)

Any help or thoughts would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you recreate the issue if you use some local geojson in jsfiddle or plunker?

Comment: I'm using ajax for getting data out of PostGIS. Is it even possible to reproduce it on local geojsons using ajax at all? I can share you my dev html: https://biking.pomorskie.eu/ptr_test/trasy_rowerowe.php

Comment: I'm sure there's a way to do it. I'll try to take a look at your link.

Comment: I haven't figured out what's going wrong yet, but wanted to offer some advice. You should pull the code to build the Trasy popups into a function so it can be reused.   It also looks like you're calling bindPopup 2 times for the R10 and WTR layers. I don't think that's the cause of the issue though.

Comment: Nothing is sticking out to me that looks wrong. I was able to capture the response for the R10 request and grab some of the geojson out of there. I'd suggest grabbing 2 small pieces of that and assigning it to a variables in your code. Then I'd hook up 2 of the checkboxes to add/remove those small pieces of geojson and see if you can figure out whats going wrong. If you make a plunker or fiddle of that I can take a look again.

Comment: Great advice with pulling out building popup content out of each layer creation. Please look at the results under different link: https://biking.pomorskie.eu/dev/trasy_rowerowe.php

Comment: @pk. i'll try to make a plunker. It's strange because I'm now able after checking new checkbox to remove existing allLayers featureGroup, add it again and bindPopup on it again, but it's the same - only newly checked layer is clickable and has popup. Previous layers are just visible, nothing else. It's part of my code inside creating new layer function: mymap.removeLayer(allLayers)
                    allLayers.bindPopup('ghaga')
                    allLayers.addTo(mymap);

Comment: @pk. I've just took another approach (probably more align with best practices) to load all Trasy data at the beginning and use filters, according to this topic: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/307985/multiple-on-the-fly-filtering-based-on-markers-features-on-leaflet. Nevertheless thanks for looking into it. If I'd have more time I'd dig into my initial issue, because it's kind of strange.

Comment: Glad to hear you got things working better. Good luck with the project.